# Is it "moved into" or "moved in to"?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, idioms, prepositions, expressions

I suppose I am confused in general about the use of "into" versus "in to." For this case, though, consider the sentence, "I moved into my apartment today" as opposed to "I moved in to my apartment today." I like the sound of "moved into," but is "moved in" like an idiom that needs to be left in that form to work? Any assistance in sorting out my confusion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At http://www.thefreedictionary.com/move+in , the Collins entry for 'move in' is:

> **move in** [AHD says this is a phrasal verb] [so, a set expression]
>
> vb (mainly adverb)
>
> 1. (also preposition) Also (when preposition) **move into**: to occupy or take possession of (a new residence, place of business, etc.) or  help (someone) to do this

I'd prefer them to have

> **move in**
>
> vb (multi-word) (mainly used without an object)
>
> 1. (can also be used in this sense with an object) (the variant **move into** is usually preferred though *when* used with an object):  to occupy or take possession of (a new residence, place of business, etc) or help (someone) to do this
>
> *They moved in last Thursday.*
>
> *We're moving into a new flat next week.*

Notice that 'move into' in  *We're moving into a new flat next week.* has a different meaning from 'move' +  'into' in say *The basilisk moved into the side-passage*.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63763/discussion-on-answer-by-edwin-ashworth-is-it-moved-into-or-moved-in-to).

Answer (score 1):

The verb is *move*. *Into* is a preposition complemented by *my apartment*. The construction  contrasts with that found with a phrasal verb like *give in*, which requires *to* to be written separately in a sentence like *I gave in to temptation, and had another beer*.

Comment: No; 'move in' and 'move into' are more cohesive than V + adv/prep when used in the 'take up residence (in)' sense. AHD and other sources label 'move in' a 'phrasal verb', and some include 'move into' as the transitive variant.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean "to switch residences," then make it two words because *move in* is a phrasal verb there. Prepositions in phrasal verbs become adverbs, and therefore, it is wrong to mix the adverb *in* in the verb *move in* with the preposition *to*. If you mean "to walk into the building," then make it one word because the verb there is *move*, and *into* tells us where you have moved (walked).

I'm sure you mean "to change residences," so make it like so.

***I have moved in to my new apartment today.***

Sources

1. http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/move-in
2. http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/definitions/into-vs-in-to/#comment-65310
3. http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/in-to-or-into?page=1 (reasoning)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63764/discussion-on-answer-by-black-and-white-is-it-moved-into-or-moved-in-to).

Comment: @tchrist Didn't you lock this post? Or did you recently unlock it?

Answer (score 0):

"Into" is like "onto"… both necessarily dictate movement.

"I moved it onto the table" but "I put it on the table".

Going "into" (any space) describes the action of *moving from another space to* that one… thankfully!

Going "in to" (any space) describes the action of *entering* that space *for a reason*

"We moved into the apartment" or "we moved the table into the apartment" are fine, as is "we put the table in the apartment" but we cannot say "we moved/put ourselves in…"

Here, "we *moved* in to…" is a misnomer for "we *went* in to…"

"We moved in to…" might work in grammar, but idiom insists we use that form only in special circumstances, as when soldiers "moved in to clear the enemy out…". There, it should be clear that the area/place/space into which they moved is not clearly specified; their movement "in" and the enemy's "out" are conceptual.

Grammatically, that's the same as "we *moved* in to clean…" but idiomatically, we would normally only ever say "we *went* in to clean…" because in both cases, "…in to…" means "…in for the purpose of (cleaning)…".

Only if we were using sports-type terminology to compare our operation to a military mission might we say that we "…moved in to clean…"

Answer (score -1):

**In** and **into** are quite separate. That said, **into** is often shortened to “**in**”, and this is where confusion may arise.

**In** is a locative preposition (it tells you where something is = within or inside [an area or volume]
**Into** is a preposition of motion or change.
**In to** = adverb (inwards) + preposition

Compare

1 John is walking **in** the garden – John is in the garden (place) and he is walking.

2 John is walking **into** the garden – John is entering (motion) the garden.

(The water changed into ice/The water changed in a few seconds.)

**To move in** is a phrasal verb = to take up residence “He has **moved in** to the castle.”

(Phrasal verbs comprise verb + adverb)

OED

> **to move in** 1. intransitive. **To take up residence with another person; to take possession of a new place of residence; to occupy new premises.**)
>
> 1999   P. Straub Mr. X xv. 77   After Star discovered that she was pregnant, I [suggested]..that she move in with me.

We would not say “After Star discovered that she was pregnant, I [suggested]..that she move **inwith** me.”

I [moved in] verb [with her.] adjunct / prepositional phrase

As far as your difficulty is concerned,

*“I moved into the apartment”* And *“I moved in to the apartment.”* are theoretically as different as 1 and 2 above.

“I pushed the door open and looked inside. I took a deep breath and moved **into** the apartment” – this is the equivalent of “I **entered** the apartment.”

**Move** is the verb and **into the apartment** is the adjunct.

“I pushed the door open and looked inside. I took a deep breath and moved in to the apartment” – this is the equivalent of “I took up residence in the apartment.”

**Move in** is the verb and **to the apartment** is the adjunct.